# Meteor Heroku Push: /bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: newline unexpected

Tags: node.js, heroku, meteor

I have just started getting an odd error when pushing to Heroku with my Meteor app.

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Fetching set buildpack https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git... done
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: -----> Installing node
remote: -----> Installing meteor
remote: /bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: newline unexpected
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

Does anyone have any thoughts as to what this newline error is indicating or what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error ist happing for everyone right now, since Meteor has an error on its install script page: [http://install.meteor.com](https://install.meteor.com/)

Comment: There's got to be a better way for us to know about this in advance?